# cómo obtener e.target.textContent in td contentEditable={true} y pasarlo a otro componente?

Tags: reactjs, html-tabla, table

Soy nuevo en reactjs. Estoy trabajando con una tabla haciendo un CRUD básico usando MERN.

Toda va bien y ahora quiero editar la celda en situ, obtener ese valor y enviarlo a un componente(boton editar) para que dicho boton haga un put request y se actualicen los valores de la tabla en la base de datos

para editar lso valores de la tabla hice lo siguiente

```
<td onInput={(e) => e.target.textContent} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.responsable}</td>
<td onInput={(e) => e.target.textContent} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.noSello}</td>
<td onInput={(e) => e.target.textContent} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.identificadorEquipo}</td>
```

entonces quiero poder enviar los valores de los e.target.textContent a mi componente(boton editar) que se encuentra en el mismo lugar que la tabla de esta forma:

```
<EditButton value1={td1} value2={td2} value3={td3}/>
```

pero cuando asigno los  `e.target.textContent` a una variable esta no las puedo pasar al componente, o sea no me deja hacer esto:

```
<td onInput={(e) => { var td1 = e.target.textContent}} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.responsable}</td>
<td onInput={(e) => {{ var td2 = e.target.textContent}} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.noSello}</td>
<td onInput={(e) => {{ var td3 = e.target.textContent}} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.identificadorEquipo}</td>


<EditButton value1={td1} value2={td2} value3={td3}/>
```

da el siguiente valor: td1 is not defined
y td1 is asigned a value  but never used

1. Como podria vincular estos valores.
2. estoy utilizando la aproximacion correcta a este problema?

Comment: ¿Porque no usar un input en cada `td` y controlar su estado con ReactJS? Así en vez de usar textContext envías el value de cada input. Saludos

Comment: podrias ponerme un ejemplo? el valor por defecto que tendria que mostrar la celda seria {informacion.responsable} etc